# jqgrid json data parsererror

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid, parse-error

My json data returned from server is like this:

```
{
    "total": "3",
    "page": "1",
    "records": "21",
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "6007",
            "cell": [
                "6007",
                "xxx",
                "",
                "22.2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "6008",
            "cell": [
                "6008",
                "xxx",
                "",
                "22.2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "6009",
            "cell": [
                "xxx",
                "xxx",
                "",
                "22.2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "6011",
            "cell": [
                "6011",
                "xxx",
                "",
                "22.2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "6012",
            "cell": [
                "6012",
                "xxx",
                "",
                "22.2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "6013",
            "cell": [
                "6013",
                "xxx",
                "",
                "22.2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "6014",
            "cell": [
                "6014",
                "xxx",
                "",
                "22.2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "6015",
            "cell": [
                "6015",
                "xxx",
                "",
                "22.2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "6016",
            "cell": [
                "6016",
                "xxx",
                "",
                "22.2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "6017",
            "cell": [
                "6017",
                "xxx",
                "",
                "22.2"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using this jqGrid Declaration in the jquery ready function:

```
 jQuery('#jqGrid1').jqGrid({
                caption: 'test grid',
                url: 'myurl',
                datatype: 'json',
                colNames: ["Column1", "Column2", "Weight", "NetWeight"],
                colModel: [
                    { "index": "Id", "width": 50, "name": "PartId" },
                    { "index": "Name","width": 100, "name": "CHNPartName" },
                    { "index": "Weight", "width": 75, "name": "Weight" },
                    { "index": "NetWeight", "name": "NetWeight"}
                ],
                viewrecords: true,
                loadError: jqGrid_aspnet_loadErrorHandler,
                pager:jQuery('#Pager1'),
                width: '640'
            });
```

but  occur parsererror in the response , anyone can help me? thanks .

Comment: what version of jqgrid? what version of jquery? what is the exact error message?

Comment: jqGrid  4.1.1 ,jquery 1.5.1.  status in loadError function is 'parsererror'

Comment: I changed jquery 1.5.1 to 1.6.2,it work correctly, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you just not set correctly the [Content-Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) of the HTTP header of the server response. In case of the JSON data it should be "application/json" corresponds to [RFC4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627). If you use static file to hold the text data you can try to rename the file extension to ".json". Look at [the demo](http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/simon.htm) which shows that your JSON data can be read by jQuery 1.6.2 without any problem.

Comment: Thanks for @Oleg reply,  I don't use static file. I can see that the Content-Type of the HTTP header of server response is "application/json; charset=utf-8" in the Firebug. very confused.

Comment: @Simon: The value "application/json; charset=utf-8" for the "Content-Type" is also correct. If you has your testpage online I could look at this and find the error. How you see from [my demo](http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/simon.htm) the problem is not in the JSON data itself and not in the jqGrid settings. It must be in the on the level of HTTP headers. Typically if the Content-Type is not corresponds to the data the JSON data will be parsed as XML data for example and you have the parsing error.

Comment: sorry,@Oleg , there's no online testpage. Everything work well under jQuery 1.6.2 and 1.4.4,just occur this error in 1.5.x. as you said above, there should be no problem in the header of response.I think ,are there any difference on ajax settings or json parsing between 1.5.x and the others?

Comment: @Simon: I don't understand why your demo should work with under jQuery 1.6.2 and 1.4.4, but not with jQuery 1.5.x in your environment. My version of your demo works without any problem with jQuery 1.5.x. See [here](http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/simon1.htm). So I suppose that the data which you use are do a little other as you posted. Nevertheless if you can use jQuery 1.6.2 without any problem I would recommend you to use it.

Comment: By the way,I used jstree plugin that also obtain data via json,when I set 'dataType' of ajax settings to 'json',also occur parsererror, if set to 'text json', it works under jQuery 1.5.x. Why? Maybe is because my environment problem?@Oleg

Comment: @Simon: Sorry, but I don't use jstree myself. Probably you have some compatibility problems?

Comment: I find the reasons of this error, Asp.Net MVC 3 project used jquery-validation plugin ,it is not compatible with jQuery 1.5 as described on [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8118). WebSite work correctly after removing jquery-validation plugin. @Oleg

Comment: jquery-validation plugin 1.7 is not compatible with jQuery 1.5.

Comment: @Simon: OK, interesting! I would try always with the last one versions of all plugins: jquery-validation 1.8.1 (see [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#jQuery_Validation_Releases_on_the_CDN_2), jQuery 1.6.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.14, jqGrid 4.1.1 but **include only the files which you really use**.